# Как протестировать добавление элемента в массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, тестирование

Задание:

> Дан целочисленный массив С(n). Вставить новый элемент перед последним максимальным элементом массива.

Решение.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <algorithm>  // Если использовать std::copy
//#include <cstring>    // Если использовать memcpy

const int C[] = { 58, 7, 85, 65, 85, 85, 9, 8, 45, 22 };
const int newValue = 1000;

int main()
{
    const size_t arrSize = sizeof(C)/sizeof(C[0]);

    int max = C[0];
    size_t index = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        if (C[i] >= max) {
            max = C[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    int* D = new int[arrSize + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        D[i] = C[i];
    D[index] = newValue;
    for (size_t i = index + 1; i < arrSize + 1; ++i)
        D[i] = C[i-1];

    /* Можно также использовать std::copy.
        std::copy(C, C + index, D);
        D[index] = newValue;
        std::copy(C + index, C + arrSize, D + index + 1);
     */

    /* А ещё можно memcpy.
        memcpy(D, C, sizeof(C[0]) * index);
        D[index] = newValue;
        memcpy(D + index + 1, C + index, sizeof(C[0])* (arrSize - index));
     */

    printf("Исходный массив:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
        printf(" %d", C[i]);

    printf("\n\nМодифицированный массив:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrSize + 1; ++i)
        printf(" %d", D[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Допущена ошибка, которая проявляется во всех вариантах реализации и не видна в авторском тестовом примере.
Вопрос: как принято тестировать подобные моменты?

Comment: хаха, как будто тестировщики умеют тестировать код. Код тестируют сами программисты.

Comment: Ошибка, надеюсь, состоит в нерассмотрении случая нулевого размера? Крайние размеры — стандартный тест.

Comment: @Vlad Дело не в размере, а в алгоритме и в тестовом примере. Они идеально подошли друг к другу.

Comment: Да никак их не протестируешь... Единственный вариант который я вижу - после нахождения данных, на которых ошибка есть, добавлять из в test case.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Алгоритмическую ошибку не вижу :) Вижу лишь проблему при `arrSize == 0` и `arrSize == MAXUINT`.

Comment: @Vlad В таком виде ошибки нет. Переформулирую вопрос.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Достаточно для примерных данных убедиться. что в требуемой позиции находится новый элемент, и тогда выяснится, что представленное вами решение не удовлетворяет поставленной задаче, так как массив не изменился.:)

Comment: @VladD Вообще-то при `arrSize==0` нет проблемы... При `MAXUINT` есть.

Comment: @kff: При `arrSize == 0` `int max = C[0];` есть UB.

Comment: @VladD А, да... Что-то не посмотрел на инициализацию... Смотрел только на использование `arrSize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нужно различать black box- и white box-тестирование.

При black box-тестировании тестировщики не видят алгоритм, и должны составить тестовые наборы данных, проверяя ТЗ. То есть, подготовка массива данных, вставка максимума на заранее выбранное место, и проверка желаемого результата. Разумеется, они должны включить типичные крайние случаи, которые часто забывают программисты:

- Что если максимумов много?
- Что если весь массив состоит из максимумов?
- Что если максимумов вовсе нет (массив пуст)?
- Что если максимум расположен на первом месте? На последнем?
- Что если среди элементов есть отрицательные/нули? Все отрицательные/все нули?
- Что если параметры каким-то образом неверны? (Например, `C == nullptr`?)
- Что если среди элементов есть максимально возможные для его типа? Минимально возможные? Что если такие элементы все? Если только на первом/последнем месте? Для случая действительных чисел, что если среди элементов массива есть бесконечность (положительная и/или отрицательная)?
- Для случая действительных чисел, что если среди элементов массива есть NaN? Если NaN'ов много? Если весь массив из NaN'ов?
- Что если копия массива не помещается в свободную память? Что если стек почти исчерпан? Что если увеличенная длина массива больше пределов для данного языка?

Набор тесткейсов зависит от опытности тестировщика, и знания им предметной области.

Для случая white box-тестирования, тестируется конкретная имплементация. Подбираются тестовые данные, которые прогоняют алгоритм по всем возможным веткам, и тестируется поведение в каждом из этих случаев.

Для вашего алгоритма это не так сильно поможет, так как по сути ветвлений не так много: у вас цикл (почти) фиксированного размера с одним ветвлением внутри и два цикла переменного размера.

---

Обратите внимание, что при помощи тестов очень сложно отловить undefined behaviour. Например, обращение к нулевому индексу инвалидирует всю программу, включая тесты, и может случайно выглядеть как пройденный тест.

Comment: Раскрываю карты. Я ожидал, что автор программы реализует более экономный вариант с обработкой на месте (в C++ можно сделать массив побольше, а в PHP автоматически создаётся новый элемент в хипе). В таком варианте и при таком тестовом массиве не ловится ситуация, когда забивается левый элемент  и размножается правый. Но вопрос задан не зря: во-первых, у меня недостаточно знаний в теме тестирования (и вряд ли я - исключение), а во-вторых, коллективный анализ показал, что ошибка есть всегда и даже (а на самом деле - тем более) учебные примеры требуют бдительности.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Понял. Это уже дополнительные ошибки, они по идее должны отловиться хорошо написанным тестом. Но хороший тест — результат деятельности хорошего тест-инженера.

Comment: А хороший стиль - определённая гарантия от таких ошибок.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Так и есть. Тест — лишь один из факторов, способствующих хорошему качеству конечного продукта.

Answer (score 2):

Например, в соответствии с требованиями подготавливаются эталонный набор пар входных и выходных данных. Далее для каждой эталонной пары: подаем программе входные, получаем результат который сравниваем с эталонным выходом.

В процессе дальнейшей разработки или эксплуатации в случае обнаружении ошибок, а это может быть если эталонный набор не содержит данные проверяющие выявленные ошибки (комбинации). В эталонный набор добавляются пары для проверки выявленный ошибок.

Comment: И вы с легкостью можете подготовить такие эталонные наборы, на которых ошибки не будет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Сразу прямо все не смогу ясное дело, но их нужно накапливать при обнаружении ошибок

Comment: Это все будет только после первой ошибки. До нее код может считаться корректным. Несколько лет, например :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В реальном мире так оно и есть, если вы не заметили. А в Средиземье, где вы можете сразу все варианты предусмореть, вам и тесты не понадобятся - вы сразу правильные программы писать будете.

Answer (score 2):

Изучайте матчасть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взято [отсюда](http://www.protesting.ru/testing/testcoverage.html)

Comment: Это "ответ-ссылка", не делайте так пожалуйста. Включите основные моменты в текст ответа. А ссылку укажите в качестве дополнения.

Comment: Нет, это ответ-картинка!!

Comment: Ответ полезен, спасибо. И он прекрасно дополняет основной.